# Laravel withSum of two columns with additional where clause

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have one to many relationship between Warehouse and Sale models

warehouse.php

```
public function sales () {
    return $this->hasMany(Sale::class);
}
```

The sales table has `product_price`, `quantity` and `status` columns.

I want to calculate `product_price * quantity` based on the status column.

If status is equal to 1 then `sum += product_price * quantity` and if it's to 2 then `sum-=product_price * quantity`

The status is basically tells if the products are delivered or returned

I tried to do it the eloquent using `withSum` but I didn't seem to get anywhere. I'm wondering if anyone has a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it at the collection level after getting all related `sales` from a `Warehouse` like so:

```php
$sales = $warehouse->sales()->select([
  'id', 'product_price', 'quantity', 'status'
])->get();

$sum = 0;

$sales->each(function($sale) use(&$sum) {
    $amount = $sale->product_price * $sale->quantity;
    $sale->status == 1 ? $sum += $amount : $sum -= $amount;
});
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381193/laravel-calculate-sum-of-two-columns-with-a-condition I'll delete this question since I didn't provide what exactly I want