# Laravel calculate sum of two columns with a condition

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have this Warehouse collection I got from the database

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "warehouse": "India"
        "sales": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "warehouse_id": 1,
                "price": "120.00",
                "quantity": 1000,
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "warehouse_id": 1,
                "price": "20.00",
                "quantity": 100,
                "status": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "warehouse_id": 1,
                "price": "40.00",
                "quantity": 1000,
                "status": 2
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "warehouse": "Malaysia"
        "sales": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "warehouse_id": 2,
                "price": "160.00",
                "quantity": 100,
                "status": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to calculate the total income for each warehouse

Total income is calculated based on the sale `status` attribute

If status = 1, the products are delivered so it should add `price * quantity` to the total income

If status = 2, the products are returned so it should subtract `price * quantity` from the total income

A basic example for India warehouse:

```
total_income = 120*1000 + 20*100 - 40*1000
```

And for Malaysia:

```
total_income = 160*100
```

I tried using `Warehouse::withSum();` but it didn't get me anywhere.
I'm wondering if there's a good way to do with collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just pass a few callbacks to the collection's `sum()` method:

```php
$warehouses_collection->map(function ($warehouse) {
    return (object) [
        'id' => $warehouse->id,
        'warehouse' => $warehouse->warehouse,
        'total_income' => collect($warehouse->sales)->sum(function ($sale) {
            ((int) $sale->price) * $sale->quantity * ($sale->status == 1 ? 1 : -1)
        })
    ];
});
```

---

`WithSum` is a bit tricky to use here but calling `withAggregate` works.

```php
Warehouse::withAggregate(
    'sales as total_income',
    'sum(case when status = 1 then price * quantity when status = 2 then price * quantity * -1 else 0 end)'
)->get()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but the first method return the total income of all warehouses which is not really what I I'm looking for. I want to return a collection of warehouses with the warehouse name and the total income as attributes

Comment: Try the second option then. It should return what you want.

Comment: I'm getting this error "Numeric value out of range: 1690 BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range" Guess I should go with unsignedDecimal() instead of decimal()

Comment: Price is decimal? If that's the case you shouldn't need `cast()`. I've edited the answer.

Comment: As for column types for prices, I think it's better to go for unsigned integers and keep the values as cents (16000 cents instead of 160.00 dollars for example)

Comment: `withAggregate()` did the trick for me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use unsignedInteger and do something like $request->input('price') * 100 in the controller?

Comment: I suggest you keep your prices as integers (10000) and format it when you need to show it (`number_format(10000, 2) // 100.00`)

Comment: Will do then I'm gonna have to cast the price in the query with `cast(price as unsigned)`. Is that all?

Comment: May I ask your opinion about that status column in the sales table that handle the returns? In our use case we don't really care about customers or return reasons so I didn't bother to create a new returns table. We only store at the end of the day how many products were delivered/returned

Comment: status column is fine.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, mate!

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would go the route below:

Obviously my solution would have to be modified slightly if you aren't using completely whole numbers (as in your example). The if/else can be broadened out as well if you have more then the 2 statuses.

```
$total_income = 0;

foreach($warehouses as $warehouse)
{
    foreach($warehouse->sales as $sale)
    {
        if($sale->status = 1)
        {
            $total_income += ($sale->price * $sale->quantity);
        }else{
            $total_income -= ($sale->price * $sale->quantity); 
        }
    }
}
```

This is a crude example of what how I would do it. It seems that each 'warehouse' has a different location ex. India vs. Malaysia. My example is more about the grand total, but you could always save the results of each different warehouse in different variables, or as a key/value pair in an array (which is how I would go).